# Yii2-How to insert status column and its automatic variations if the corresponding value used by another form

Tags: mysql, yii2, status

although I have searched in various resources I cannot understand how to correctly insert the ‘status’ column, I will explain better.
I have two sql tables: [image: numerazioni]
[image: gestionepc]

From the `gestionepc form using dropdown, I can select the` numerazione`column of the`numerazioni`table and so far everything works without problems. However, I need to insert the “status” column on the`numerazioni`table so that if I use a record in the`numerazioni`column, its`status` must automatically change to “Not active” as it is already used. For my project, it is a requirement derived from the fact that I have various groups of user permissions and various authorizations.

In practice, I'm very confused about how to insert the status column (type of column, default value, storage also on the MySQL database and initialize it) and on how to make it work through the code (perhaps using `afterSave` and `beforeUpdate`).

I read Active Record from Guide Yii2 but I don’t understand.

I modify table `numerazioni` in this mode: [image: numerazioni]

And I try this in model Numerazioni

```
const STATUS_INDISPONIBILE = 'Indisponibile';
const STATUS_DISPONIBILE = 'Disponibile';

public function setStatusnumerazione()
{
    if (\app\models\Gestionepc::find()->where(!isEmpty('numerazioni_id'))) {
        $this->statusnumerazione = self::STATUS_INDISPONIBILE;
    }
    else {
        $this->statusnumerazione = self::STATUS_DISPONIBILE;
    }
}
```

But not working. Thanks in advance.